# compare and filter the two nested dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries listed below

```
old_dict = { {'laptop' : {'purchasedon': 10052022} , {'mobile' : {'purchasedon': 10052022} }
new_dict = { {'laptop' : {'purchasedon': 10062022} , {'mobile' : {'purchasedon': 10052022} , {'tab' : {'purchasedon': 10062022}  }
```

I want to compare new dictionary with the old one with following conditions.

1. new_dict has different key's (new key's)
2. new_dict old keys values has been changed
3. Remove if the key and values are same

Filter and create new dictionary based on above conditions.

**Expected Output :**

```
final_dict = { {'laptop' : {'purchasedon': 10062022}  , {'tab' : {'purchasedon': 10062022}  }
```

**My Code**

```
    final_dict = {}
    for k1, v1 in new_dict.items():  # the basic way
      if new_dict[k1]['purchaseon'] != old_dict[k1]['purchaseon']:
         final_dict = {k1: {'purchaseon': v1}}
```

I am getting key error. i don't know how to escape from it

Comment: `new_dict` does not seem to be a dictionary , from what you have posted. Its a set or list ?

Comment: You show a `set` of `dict`, but that's not possible. Should it be `{'laptop': {'purchasedon: ...}, 'phone': {...}}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you actually have a `dict` of `dict`, and not a `set` of `dict` of `dict`. The latter is not possible in Python, and the former also conforms more to your existing code.

```
>>> old_dict = {'laptop': {'purchasedon': 10052022}, 'mobile': {'purchasedon': 10052022}}
>>> new_dict = {'laptop': {'purchasedon': 10062022}, 'mobile': {'purchasedon': 10052022}, 'tab': {'purchasedon': 10062022}}
```

To fix the KeyError, you have to first check if the key is in `old_dict` before trying to access it. Also note that with `final_dict = ...` in the `if`, you overwrite the *entire* dict. You probably want `final_dict[k1] = v1` to insert just that element (`v1` is already the entire inner dict).

```
final_dict = {}
for k, v in new_dict.items():
    if k not in old_dict or old_dict[k]['purchasedon'] != v['purchasedon']:
        final_dict[k] = v
```

You can also do so in a dict comprehension:

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in new_dict.items() if k not in old_dict or old_dict[k]['purchasedon'] != v['purchasedon']}
{'laptop': {'purchasedon': 10062022}, 'tab': {'purchasedon': 10062022}}
```

If you do not actually want to compare *only* by `purchasedon`, you may also use this variant:

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in new_dict.items() if k not in old_dict or old_dict[k] != v}
{'laptop': {'purchasedon': 10062022}, 'tab': {'purchasedon': 10062022}}
```

Assuming `new_dict` does not contain `None` values, you may also use `dict.get` to get the value from `old_dict` if it exists, or `None` (and not an exception) if it does not.

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in new_dict.items() if old_dict.get(k) != v}
{'laptop': {'purchasedon': 10062022}, 'tab': {'purchasedon': 10062022}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the dict representation you made in the question is invalid, and probably looks something like

```
old_dict = {'laptop': {'purchasedon': 10052022}, 'mobile': {'purchasedon': 10052022}}
new_dict = {'laptop': {'purchasedon': 10062022}, 'mobile': {'purchasedon': 10052022},
                'tab': {'purchasedon': 10062022}}
```

You can compare the dicts for equality, and so a simple approach can be done something like below

```
# Find new keys!
new_keys = set(new_dict.keys()) - set(old_dict.keys())

# For a dict, with all new keys
final_dict = {new_key: new_dict.get(new_key) for new_key in new_keys}

# Find all records, which are not equal in both set of keys
modified_records = {ex_key: new_dict.get(ex_key) for ex_key in old_dict if
                    new_dict.get(ex_key) != old_dict.get(ex_key)}

# Create the final dict
final_dict.update(modified_records)
```

This can give you the output similar to your need

```
{"tab": {"purchasedon": 10062022}, "laptop": {"purchasedon": 10062022}}
```